# Laravel bulk insert optimization

Tags: php, performance, laravel

I'm currently using a make shift INSERT on DUPLICATE UPDATE function that relies on a DB raw query from eloquent. I'm looking to improve the quality of the code and the speed. Please take a look

```
function bulkInsertBookTable($data)
{
    $inserts = [];
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $inserts[] = implode(', ', ['"' . $item['book_id'] . '"', $item['isbn']]);
    }

    $inserts = Collection::make($inserts);

    $inserts->chunk(500)->each(function($ch) {
        $insertString = '';
        foreach ($ch as $element) {
            $insertString .= '(' . $element . '), ';
        }

        $insertString = rtrim($insertString, ", ");

        try {
            DB::insert("INSERT INTO book_datas (`book_id`, `isbn`) VALUES $insertString ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `isbn`=VALUES(`isbn`)");
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r([$e->getMessage()]);
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE:**

`createOrUpdate` function is only valid on model level and does not allow mass insert. Doing `Model::insert()` will allow to have a `$data = []` inserted as long as fillable is used however it will reject if there is a duplicate key

Comment: this really has nothing to do with Laravel .. aside from your habit to use statics

Comment: @tereško I'm using this within laravel's eloquent seeing that as I noted createOrUpdate or the other model inserts don't allow the SQL that I need to do, so it pertains specifically to laravel unless someone else is able to show me a better within laravel to do what I need to do because so far this is functional within laravel

Answer (score 1):

#### `implode` works

> ```
>         $insertString = '';
>         foreach ($ch as $element) {
>             $insertString .= '(' . $element . '), ';
>         }
>
>         $insertString = rtrim($insertString, ", ");
> ```

You can replace this section of code with just something like

```
        $insertString = '(' . implode('), (', $ch->all()) . ')';
```

This is shorter with fewer failure points.  And of course, it avoids having to trim off the extra comma at the end.

#### Bound parameters

But actually, it would be better to replace it with something like

```
        $insertString = implode(', ', array_fill(0, $ch->count(), '(?, ?)'));
```

and then pass the values to `DB::insert` as an array.  I'd write more of the code for this, but I'm not sure exactly how the Laravel `Collection` objects work.

#### Naming

Data is already plural (the singular is datum).  There is no datas.

I'd prefer `$chunk` to `$ch`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, missing one element of optimization if you can: the first foreach - any way to make it more dynamic and not rely on known keys?